# How to pass a GET variable in Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've a problem with my code. I want to pass a PHP variable to bootstrap modal.

Here's my code :

My link to open modal :

```
<td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-user" href="userDetails.php?id_user=<?= $rel['id_user'] ;?>"><?= $rel['id_user'] ;?></a></td>
```

My modal code :

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-user" aria-hidden="true" id="modal-user">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <?php
            include('userDetails.php');
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the userDetails.php code :

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

if (isset($_GET['id_user']) && !empty($_GET['id_user'])) {
    $idUser = $_GET['id_user'];
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_user=" .$bdd->quote($idUser);
$query = $bdd->query($sql);
$userDetails = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


?>

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Infos</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                    foreach($userDetails as $details) {
                ?>
                    <p><?= $details['name'] ?></p>
                    <p><?= $details['firstname'] ?></p>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also, I've this jQuery code :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#modal-user').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
</script>
```

I've looking other posts and normaly, everything must be ok but I've an error and I still don't know why...

**Notice: Undefined variable: idUser in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/directory/userDetails.php on line 10**

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap modal `href` is not calling your page when you click. Your page is already loaded when you `include` `userDetails.php`. So you can define the get before the `include` or pass the user id through `GET` variable.

So:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-user" aria-hidden="true" id="modal-user">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <?php
            $_GET['id_user'] = $rel['id_user'];
            include('userDetails.php');
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

**In a LOOP**

If you have a loop and want to do it dynamically through the `jQuery` you can do the following:

Remove the bootstrap calls from your link, and add a trigger class `modal-btn` and make it like:

```
<a 
    class="btn btn-primary modal-btn btn-xs"
    href="userDetails.php?id_user=<?= $rel['id_user'] ;?>"><?= $rel['id_user'] ;?>
</a>
```

Update your modal structure and remove the `include()`:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-user" aria-hidden="true" id="modal-user"> 
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">   
    <div class="modal-content"></div>    
  </div> 
</div>
```

The jQuery should get the `href` property of the link and call the `bootstrap` modal function `load` and also force the modal to `show`

```
$(".modal-btn").on('click',function(e){ //trigger when link clicked
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $('#modal-user').modal('show'); //force modal to show
   $('.modal-content').load( $(this).attr('href')); //load content from link's href
});
```

So your page `userDetails.php` will be loaded inside the modal, and you will need to remove the `<div class="modal-content">...</div>` from it to avoid duplication...